# $compile showing uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the following code. To target the particular element and append a `<div>`inside that but getting uncaught typeerror: undefined is not a function for `$compile(newDirective)($scope);`

```
 $scope.grid= function (targetElement)
  {  
     console.log("target element",targetElement)
     var newDirective = angular.element("<div style='height:200px' > 
     Sample code 
     </div>");


     targetElement.append(newDirective);


     $compile(newDirective)($scope);


  }
```

Comment: Could you give more insight on the context in which you are executing this ? Are $compile and $scope defined ?

Comment: Did you inject the `$compile` service?

Comment: It means that you didn't inject `$compile` service. Show full code.

Comment: function DashboardCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $q, $http, $timeout,$compile) ..... I am adding these line to inject the $scope and $compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
 $scope.grid= function (targetElement)
      {  
       var $div = $("<div style='height:200px' >  Sample code </div>");
       $(targetElement).append($div);

       angular.element(targetElement).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
       var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
       $compile($div)(scope);
      });
     }
```