# Empty Quotes In jQuery Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to add a link after a black of text.  I can get them to render just fine, but the link `href` tag just disappears.

```
var eventstuff = data.text;
var eventElement = $("<div class='well well-sm eventsWells'>");
var deleteButton = $("<div class='panel'><a style='float:right; color:#348CD9; margin-top:3px;' href='' ng-click='deleteEvent("+key+")'>DELETE</a></div>");
eventElement.html(eventstuff).append(deleteButton);
eventsList.append(eventElement);
```

But the **html** just shows:

```
<a style="float:right; color:#348CD9; margin-top:3px;" href ng-click="deleteEvent(-KAY7j7_deUWLjhDbaQ5)">DELETE</a>
```

and clicking the link takes me to */#* (using Angular).

I've tried using `href='#'` and putting return false at the end, which also didn't work, it still redirected to */#*.

I've also tried escaping the quotation marks, and removing the `href`, both of which don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to call `deleteEvent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might because of `deleteEvent(-KAY7j7_deUWLjhDbaQ5)`.

Correct onclick when you are passing `string` type parameter should be like this:

```
deleteEvent('-KAY7j7_deUWLjhDbaQ5')
            ^                    ^ // ==>quotes are requried
```

This you can achieve by using following like:

```
var deleteButton = $("<div class='panel'><a style='float:right; color:#348CD9; margin-top:3px;' href='' ng-click='deleteEvent(\'"+key+"\')'>DELETE</a></div>");
```

### Updates

You need to add `$compile` service here, that will bind the angular directives like `ng-click` to your controller scope. See following:

```
var eventstuff = data.text;
var eventElement = $("<div class='well well-sm eventsWells'>");
var deleteButton = $("<div class='panel'><a style='float:right; color:#348CD9; margin-top:3px;' href='' ng-click='deleteEvent(\'"+key+"\')'>DELETE</a></div>");
$compile(deleteButton)($scope);  //here
$compile(eventElement)($scope);  //here
eventElement.html(eventstuff).append(deleteButton);
eventsList.append(eventElement);
```

Comment: Man, it's really not liking qoutes... when I add ng-click='deleteEvent('" + key + "') I get <a style="float:right; color:#348CD9; margin-top:3px;" href="" ng-click="deleteEvent(" -kay7j7_deuwljhdbaq5')'="">DELETE</a>

Comment: See my answer i have added line of assigning HTML. You need to escape quote with \ back-slash

Comment: that's not working either, it's still going to /#.  Might need to give up on doing it this way.

Comment: Just show me which HTML its generating. and see updated answer.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469476/compile-showing-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function

Comment: Got it added, now it's saying "Unexpected end of expression: deleteEvent("

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103456/discussion-between-manwal-and-alteredorange).

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this 
href='javascript:void(0);' ng-click='deleteEvent(\""+key+\"")'